# function for calculate specific mod in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, biginteger, modulo

I have four big numbers (up to 100 digits) like `m, y, n, r` that `m * y mod n = r`. I know the value of `m,n` and `r` and I wanna find the value of `y`. Is there a function in `python3` to do this? (like the `powmod` function in `gmpy2`)

Comment: Can't you just use the property `(m * y) mod n = (m mod n) * (y mod n) mod n` ?

Comment: What you ask is nothing like `powmod`. You are asking for division in modular arithmetic, which usually uses the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). This is pretty easy to implement yourself, but be careful to check for error conditions.

Comment: I know, I just say an example that I need such this function @RoryDaulton

Comment: Are you asking how to do this, or specifically only if there is a built-in function that does this?

Comment: a built-in function @RoryDaulton

Comment: and how can this help, when (m mod n) and (y mod n) are the big numbers again? @RojanKarakaya

Comment: How can I pretty easy to implement this and find y? @RoryDaulton

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `r` in your problem is guaranteed to be `1`, there are some available Python functions, such as the `invert` function in the gmpy or [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) modules. I have not found the more general division function that you want. You could use the standard invert functions, but they will disallow some divisions that can actually be done.

Here is a function that I just wrote, based on [sample code in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers), as efficient as I can make it. With your terminology, call `divideresidues(r, m, n)`.

```
def divideresidues(dividend, divisor, modulus):
    """Return the dividend / divisor modulo modulus"""
    r, newr = modulus, divisor
    t, newt = 0, 1
    while newr != 0:
        quotient, remainder = divmod(r, newr)
        r, newr = newr, remainder
        t, newt = newt, t - quotient * newt
    if t < 0:
        t = t + modulus
    quotient, remainder = divmod(dividend, r)
    if remainder:
        raise ValueError('Bad division in divideresidues()')
    return t * quotient % modulus
```

This has the same efficiency as the Euclidean algorithm, namely five times the number of digits in the smaller of `divisor` and `modulus`. The size of `dividend` is basically irrelevant. In your case that means at most 500 steps. This sounds like a large number but I tested it with larger numbers and it seems fast enough, and those 500 steps will happen rarely--basically when `divisor` and `modulus` are successive numbers in the Fibonacci sequence.